# auto upload image from your computer to database using php

Tags: php

There is a problem when i try to upload my image that i show in register form to the database
i already tried searching so many website and here also, but not able to find the answer, hope some of you can help me to solve it. thx

here is my code
just half of it

```
<td  align="center" colspan="3" ><table border="1" bgcolor="white" width="100" height="100" ><tr><td align="center">**<img src="image/profil.jpg" name="image">**</tr></td></table></td></tr><tr>
<td valign="top" width="50%">Email</td><td>:</td><td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" /></td></tr><tr>


$email=$_POST['email'];
        $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
        $password1=$_POST['password1'];
        $password2=$_POST['password2'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $bday = $_POST['day'];
        $bmonth = $_POST['month'];
        $byear = $_POST['year'];
        $countrys = $_POST['country'];
        $photo=$_POST['photo'];

        // CEK IF DATA NOT EMPTY
        if($email=='' || $first_name=='' || $password1=='' || $password2=='' || $gender=='' || $bday=='' || $bmonth=='' || $byear=='' || $countrys==''){
            echo '<h2>Maaf, data Anda tidak lengkap</h2>';

        }else{
            //cek if password anda retype password in same
            if($password1!=$password2){
                echo '<h2>Password Anda tidak sama!</h2>';

            }else{
                //save data to database
                // creating query
                $query="INSERT INTO user_login (email, first_name, last_name, password, gender, b_day, b_month, b_year, country) VALUES 
                ('$email', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$password1', '$gender', '$bday', '$bmonth', '$byear', '$countrys','$photo')";
```

please.thx

Answer (score 0):

For image upload use

```
<input type="file" name="photo" />
```

In case of file type fields make sure to add enctype attribute on your form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Uploaded image will be available in $_FILES super global rather than $_POST

For the file path use `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_path']`

Comment: no sir, sorry, but the file i want to upload is not with like user have to browse the image, but it's automatically when someone register, the default profil picture also automatic uploaded to my database.hmm

Comment: in that case you can directly mention the path of your default profile picture rather then getting dependent on the post data

Comment: ow, can u tell me how , with some code maybe ? sorry i am very newbie,i have to finish my project from college :D

Comment: the value which you are expecting in post for the profile picture you can directly use that image path value in your database query
Imp : image type field does not get posted

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="first_name"/>
<input type="text" name="last_name"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<!-- etc.. !-->
</form>
```

Then you should get your file 
upload.php

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

You should save the $target_file into your table.